# $lookup not allow in $facet mongodb v4.4

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In mongoose v5.5.10 and MongoDB v4.4.0, I can use $lookup in $facet to join multiple collections.

Description: I need to search on multiple collections using $text search in MongoDB, and I'm using aggregation pipeline stages to query data from those collections.
Ex:

```
const itemsFound = await this.collection.aggregate([
  { $sort: sort },
  {
    $facet: {
      col1: [
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'collection1',
            pipeline: [{
              $match: {
                ...restCondition,
              },
            }],
            as: 'collection1',
          },
        },
      ]
```

On MongoDB version v4.2(v4.2.8). It's working perfect.

But in the MongoDB v4.4.0, $lookup does not allow in $facet.
And here this is my error.

[image]

Does anyone have the information about this issue?

Comment: its working, what are you getting in error?

Comment: Describe your problem, it should work

Comment: I'm updated my issue, thank you